# discord.py Extracting information from api with query parameters

Tags: api, discord.py

I'm quite new to the aspect of using API with discord.py and I seem to be having issues when it comes to extracting data with query parameters.

My code is as follows:

```
@command(name="characterID",  aliases=["cid"])
    async def character_info(self, ctx, characterID):
        URL="https://c2s1.op-framework.com/op-framework/character.json"


        async with request("GET", URL, headers={}, params=characterID) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                data = await response.json()
                substring = data["data"]
                await ctx.send(f"The CID {characterID} has the following info:\n{substring}")
```

My goal here is to extract information from a certain character ID but upon running my command I end up with substring = []. I've been reading the documentation and I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong. If someone could enlighten me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

I am provided with the following [documentation](https://docs.opfw.net/#public-routes-character-json):

/character.json - > Returns information about a certain character.

Query parameters:

**FIELD**: characterId      **TYPE**:integer    **DESCRIPTION**: The character id you need information about.

The expected output for substring should be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "steamIdentifier": "steam:11000010d322da9",
        "firstName": "Kye",
        "lastName": "Clancy",
        "fullName": "Kye Clancy"
    }
]
```

If my problem is unclear or needs further details as to what I have tried so far feel free to let me know and thank you.

Comment: First of all, Do not use ```requests``` for async environments. Use ```aiohttp```.

Comment: Don't know anything about the API you are using but have you tried printing out `data` and seeing what it looks like. I think once you do that, you can get a better idea of where things may be going wrong.